# If $T$ is bounded, then $\|Tf\|_{F}\leq \|T\|\|f\|_{E}$ for all $f\in E$.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, normed-spaces

**Proposition**

A linear operator $T:E\to F$ is bounded ($\|Tf\|_{F}\leq c\|f\|_{E}$) if and only if its operator norm
\begin{align*}
\|T\| := \|T\|_{\mathcal{L}(E,F)} := \sup_{\|f\|_{E}\leq 1}\|Tf\|_{F}
\end{align*}
is a finite number and $\mathcal{L}(E,F)$ indicates the space of bounded linear operators from $E$ to $F$. If $T$ is bounded, then
\begin{align*}
\|Tf\|_{F}\leq \|T\|\|f\|_{E}\,\,\text{for all}\,\,f\in E \tag{1}
\end{align*}

**Proof**

If $\|Tf\|\leq c\|f\|$ for all $f\in E$, then obviously $\|T\|\leq c$, hence $\|T\|$ is finite.

If $\|T\| < \infty$, then for a general $f\in E$, $f\neq 0$, we write $\lambda := \|f\|$ and compute
\begin{align*}
\|Tf\| = \|T(\lambda\lambda^{-1}f)\| = \lambda\|T(\lambda^{-1}f)\| \leq \lambda\|T\| = \|T\|\|f\|
\end{align*}
since $\|\lambda^{-1}f\| = \lambda^{-1}\|f\| = 1$. This establishes $(1)$ for $f\neq 0$. But $\|T(0)\| = \|0\| = 0$, and hence $(1)$ also holds for $f = 0$.

**My concerns**

I am a little bit lost as to the part where the author says that "obviously $\|T\|\leq c$".

As far as I have understood, if the relation holds for every $f\in E$, if we take the sup from both sides, one concludes that
\begin{align*}
\|T\| = \sup_{\|f\|\leq 1}\|Tf\| \leq \sup_{\|f\|\leq 1}c\|f\| = c
\end{align*}

As to the second part, the author states that $\|T(\lambda^{-1}f)\|\leq\|T\|$, but I am not able to understand why does it hold.

Could someone please help me understand it properly?

Answer (score 2):

You have already proved the $\|T\| \le c$ at the bottom of the post.

For the second question, note that from the definition of $\lambda$, $\|\lambda^{-1} f\| = 1$, so the definition of $\|T\|$ implies $\|T(\lambda^{-1} f)\| \le \|T\|$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

$$\|T\|=\sup_{\|f\|\le1}\|T(f)\|\le\sup_{\|f\|\le1}c\|f\|=c\sup_{\|f\|\le1}\|f\|\le c$$

Note that $$\|\lambda^{-1}f\|=\|f\|^{-1}\|f\|=1$$

Therefore

$$||T(\lambda^{-1}f)\|\le\sup_{\|g\|\le1}\|T(g)\|=\|T\|$$